# Accessing array pointed to by pointer in reverse order using recursive function

Tags: c

I am accessing array in reverse order but it's giving me segFault at `int temp=arr[n-1]+abc(arr[n-1],n-1);` in main and the function code is below. segFault when n=2

```
int abc(int *arr, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;

    int temp = arr[n - 1] + abc(arr[n - 1], n - 1);
    // I also tried   int temp=arr[n-1]+abc(arr+(n-1),n-1); segFault goes away but print garbage or address of elements of array
    printf("%d\n", temp);
    return temp;
}

void main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    abc(arr, 3);
}
```

I also tried   `int temp=arr[n-1]+abc(arr+(n-1),n-1);` and segFault goes away but prints address or garbage. So my question is isn't `arr[1]` returns the address of array pointed to by pointer `arr` of first element. How can I fix it?

Comment: `printf("%d\n",temp[n-1]);` shouldn't compile - you mean `printf("%d\n",arr[n-1]);`? Also, it's `int main()`, not `void main()`, but that shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: @KenY-N corrected with `printf("%d\n",temp)` still error or garbage

Comment: Not sure how this compiles? abc expects an array as the first input, but you're passing it an integer? I suspect you meant: 
    int temp = arr[n - 1] + abc(arr, n - 1);

Comment: Don't post code that doesn't compile cleanly without warnings.  The compiler is telling you about at least one bug in your code — heed what the compiler says.  At this stage in your career, the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.  If it deigns to warn you about something, assume that it is a bug.

Comment: @robthebloke yes thanks its working now. so the question was actually that if `arr[1]` and so on do return address of array arr from first location.. or does it return int.

Comment: If `arr` is a pointer, `arr[1]` returns one of the objects that `arr` points at — so in this context, it returns an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `abc`'s argument has the `int*` type, so you must pass argument of such the type. But you are trying pass the `arr[n - 1]` which is of `int` type.

As Ken Y-N mentioned, the `temp[n-1]` isn't a valid construction at all. The `%d` format modifier demands an integer argument, so you must provide it. The `temp` or the `arr[some_index]` or something else, but an expression must have the `int` type.

> so my question is isn't arr[1] returns the address of array pointed to by pointer arr of first element

The `arr[1]` does not return an *address*, it returns the second array's *element*. Not the first, because arrays in the C language is always zero-based indexed, so the 0 index corresponds to the first element, the 1 -- to the second etc. This is resulted from the system-orientation of the C language, so that the arrays in C may be imagined as a memory ranges which hold some data, where the indices are addresses in this memory. So, zero address represents the very beginning address in such a region.

Comment: What if I pass arr+(n-1)? Should be ok?

Comment: @user786, I'm not sure, will it be OK or not because I cannot imagine what exactly this code is designated for. The `arr + (n - 1)` expression returns the address of the n-th array member, so if your goal is to take the n'th element's address then you reached it.

Comment: Actually I tried like printing 1 3 6= 1, 1+2,1+2+3 from array 1 2 3

Comment: I was just looking at code of knapsack algo. It did achieved by this type of recursion from geeksforgeek.com

Comment: @user786, I'd like to suggest the following implementation: http://cpp.sh/3npesi

Comment: Do u know any link where I can find the list of algorithms names like knapsack and other greedy algorithms and other types of sorting & searching and all other algorithm names? I will do google search on that and want to see how they work? Can u please tell me?

Comment: @user786, No, I don't know.